# Thymeleaf fragments not working sometimes

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my Springboot project, I've included two thymeleaf fragments(head,navigator). If I remove the navigator, the code works fine and head is included in the page, otherwise it causes this error.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5">
<head th:replace ="fragments::head" />
<body>
    <div th:replace ="fragments::navigator" />

    <div class="container text-center">
    <h1>Welcome to CrDr</h1>
    <h3><a th:href="@{/users}">List of Users</a></h3>
    <h3><a th:href="@{/register}">Register</a></h3>
    <h3><a th:href="@{/login}">Login</a></h3>
    <h3><a th:href="@{/daybooks}">Daybook</a></h3>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The Error :

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error resolving fragment: "~{fragments :: navigator}": template or fragment could not be resolved (template: "index" - line 6, col 7)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
    ... 102 more
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving fragment: "~{fragments :: navigator}": template or fragment could not be resolved (template: "index" - line 6, col 7)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.FragmentExpression.resolveExecutedFragmentExpression(FragmentExpression.java:619)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
```

fragments.html contents:

```html
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:fragments = "head" >
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> [[${pageTitle}]] </title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

        <div th:fragments="navigator" >
    <div class="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a> 
  <a th:href="@{/daybooks}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i> Daybook</a> 
  <a th:href="@{/login}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a> 
  <a th:href="@{/login}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Login</a>
        </div>
</div>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Since there is this line in your stacktrace `template or fragment could not be resolved (template: "index" - line 6, col 7)`, I think there is an error in your `index.html`. Could you add the code of this file to your question?

Comment: added the index.html to my question.

Comment: How is the `navigator` fragment defined in your `fragments.html` file? Is it defined in the same way as the `head` fragment (which also appears to be in the same `fragments.html` file)? Are all these Thymeleaf template files in the same folder? If not, what is the folder structure?

Comment: navigator fragment defined in same way as the head fragment, both fragments are in the same fragments.html file and all the template files are under the templates folder. 
if I add head fragment only it works fine. when I include navigator it throws error. @andrewjames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have a couple of typos.

1. Fragment you are trying to include is `navigator`, but in the fragments file this fragment defined as `nav_bar`. Use the same fragment name.
2. Your fragments names in the "fragments.html" file set in `th:fragments` attribute, but needs to be in [`th:fragment` attribute](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#template-layout).

So the working code may look like ...

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:fragment = "head" >
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> [[${pageTitle}]] </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>    
    <div th:fragment="navigator" >
        <div class="navbar">
        <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a> 
        <a th:href="@{/daybooks}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i> Daybook</a> 
        <a th:href="@{/login}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a> 
        <a th:href="@{/login}"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Login</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The fragments name mismatch is because I added the fragments.html content to the post after a user asked it, so the only problem is I used ```th:fragments``` instead of ```th:fragment```.  Additionally I would be helpful if anyone can explain why it works for head frangment.